# Google maps react marker not showing

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-react

Im new in react
I've tried to use google maps, I want to get latlng by click on map and showing the marker
I found and have tried [this][1]

it work, I can choose the location that I want and get latlng by click on map, but the marker is not showing

here's my code

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const { lat, lng } = await this.getcurrentLocation();
    this.setState(prev => ({
      fields: {
        ...prev.fields,
        location: {
          lat,
          lng
        }
      },
      currentLocation: {
        lat,
        lng
      }
    }));
  }
   getcurrentLocation() {
    if (navigator && navigator.geolocation) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(pos => {
          const coords = pos.coords;
          resolve({
            lat: coords.latitude,
            lng: coords.longitude
          });
        });
      });
    }
    return {
      lat: 0,
      lng: 0
    };
  }
  addMarker = (location, map) => {
    this.setState(prev => ({
      fields: {
        ...prev.fields,
        location
      }
    }));
    map.panTo(location);
    alert(location);
  };


in render 

<Map
    google={this.props.google}
     style={{
      width: "auto",
      height: "300px",
      position: "relative"
     }}
      onClick={(t, map, c) => this.addMarker(c.latLng, map)}

      zoom={14}
      >
      {(marker => {
        return <Marker position={this.state.fields.location}
       />
      })};
 Map>
```

thanks

Comment: Which package you are using?

Comment: google-maps-react

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was in how **I was conditionally adding the markers**.

In the markers' icons definitions, I use `google.maps` methods, so there is a need to wait till the map will be completely loaded. When I was using the direct `setState` method, the `Marker` component **did never render**:

```
<GoogleMap
  ...
  onLoad={(map) => setMapInstance(map)}
>
  {mapInstance && <Marker position={...} icon={...} />}
</GoogleMap>
```

**But when I used the `setTimeout`** to set the instance up: `onLoad={(map) => setTimeout(() => setMapInstance(map))}`, everything worked as a charm

Full example:

```
    <GoogleMap
      ...
      onLoad={(map) => setTimeout(() => setMapInstance(map))}
    >
      {mapInstance && (
          <Marker 
             position={location} 
             icon={{
               url: markerUrl,
               scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(markerSize, markerSize),
               origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
               anchor: new google.maps.Point(markerSize / 2, markerSize / 2),
            }} 
          />
      )}
    </GoogleMap>
```

Comment: setTimeout worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
<Marker
    title={'The marker`s title will appear as a tooltip.'}
    name={'SOMA'}
    position={{lat: 37.778519, lng: -122.405640}} />
```

Add this code manually and check if Marker is working or not. Please double check if you are getting `lat` and `lng` by `console.log()`

Comment: yes the marker is shwoing, but when I click in another place the marker not appear where I click

Answer (score 0):

Use [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) to render marker component, for example:

```
{this.state.fields.location && <Marker position={this.state.fields.location}/>}
```

or

```
{
     this.state.fields.location ?
       <Marker position={this.state.fields.location}/> : null
}
```

[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hbpsrw)